# Setting up tours

Tags: 8

I think I have two pretty straight questions about the tours and tours ui module but I can't seem to find the answers. Sorry for putting them in one post it seems more logic this way.

1. How can I create a custom tours button to call the tour on the current page. The default button is shown in my admin menu but I want it to show to people who don't have access to the admin menu as well.
   I know I can do this with a simple `<a href="/page/?tour=1">link</a>` but this makes the page reload and this doesn't happen with the default button. So there must be another way.
2. I have to insert a route for the page where the tour should be shown. The route I can find for my content type page is `entity.node.canonical` but I think this is the route to all node pages. Is there a way to make it specific for one content type page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

If you look in tour module, there are a js/tour.js file with the logic. You could use it to figure out how it works.

```
Drupal.behaviors.tour = {
attach: function attach(context) {
  $('body').once('tour').each(function () {
    var model = new Drupal.tour.models.StateModel();
    new Drupal.tour.views.ToggleTourView({
      el: $(context).find('#toolbar-tab-tour'),
      model: model
    });

    model.on('change:isActive', function (model, isActive) {
      $(document).trigger(isActive ? 'drupalTourStarted' : 'drupalTourStopped');
    }).set('tour', $(context).find('ol#tour'));

    if (/tour=?/i.test(queryString)) {
      model.set('isActive', true);
    }
  });
 }
};
```

When you talk about default button, i think you are refering to '#toolbar-tab-tour' button, so you could write a js file following this example.

### Question 2

You are right. Tipically,you could work with this route using paramenters to build URL. For example:

```
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1], $options)
```

But you can't add these params in module Tour UI. I think the easiest approach is build a simple module and create your own route to map a node. It should be fast.

Here the [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules) for more infomation to build a module

Comment: Thanks a lot. Creating a button was as simple as creating a div with the #toolbar-tab-tour id. When the use doesn't have acces to the admin toolbar this custom div will work as the default button replacement.